# How to push different elements in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML doc. I want to push the number which is clicked in an array named as "number".

Right now If I click on 1 the number adds but if I click on 2 or 3 then too number 1 is added to the array.

I know the reason as it is taking the same id, but how to mae it add different numbers?

```
<html>
<body>
<table>

<tr>

<td id="key" onClick="addNumber()">1</td>
<td id="key" onClick="addNumber()">2</td>
<td id="key" onClick="addNumber()">3</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>

</tr>
</table>

</body>

<script>

 let number = [];
function addNumber() {
   var num = document.getElementById("key").innerHTML;
   number.push(num);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: just change to different id's ... ? it's take the first element with the id it's found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the current element to your function like this:

```
onClick="/myFunction( this )"
```

Now you can read from this element as it's the first argument passed in:

```
function myFunction( element ){ .. use element... }
```

```js
let number = [];

function addNumber( element ) {
   var num = element.innerHTML;
   number.push(num);
   console.log( number )
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td onClick="addNumber(this)">1</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(this)">2</td>
    <td onClick="addNumber(this)">3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Personally, I would approach it slightly differently, as adding `onClick` to your elements in HTML is mixing the interactive parts (JS) with your pure content, making this cumbersome to work on later. I would approach it purely in my script, just for separation of church and state:

```js
let numbers = [];

function addNumber( event ){

   numbers.push( event.target.innerHTML );
   
   // Here we will print the numbers array into the output id
   
   document.getElementById( 'output' ).innerText = '[numbers]: ' + numbers.join( ', ' );
   
}

// document.querySelectorAll selects all <td> elements
// [ ... ] will spread them out into an Array, which will
// expose the forEach method of standard Arrays on your selection

[ ...document.querySelectorAll( 'td' ) ].forEach(td => {
  
  // Here we will listen for the click events
  
  td.addEventListener( 'click', addNumber );
  
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>

  </tr>
</table>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Hey, can we print the numbers in the same array? and also print the array's element? right now in your and my code it is printing new array on every click.

Comment: @Aditya internally this _is_ the same array, it's just how `console.log` works that it prints it every time you click (since it prints the result every time you log). Internally it is still that single array stored in `number`. I am not sure what output you are looking for, its unclear from the question.

Comment: no i got it as you said that internally its the same array.this is only the doubt.you can upvote my question if its valid.

Comment: @Aditya I also added a more best-practices example of how you could implement this. That one I also changed the output of so you get the 'its the same array' more easily!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>

<tr>

<td id="key" onClick="addNumber(1)">1</td>
<td id="key" onClick="addNumber(2)">2</td>
<td id="key" onClick="addNumber(3)">3</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>

</tr>
</table>

</body>

<script>

 let number = [];
function addNumber(num) {
   number.push(num);
}
</script>
</html>
```